# Flutter TextField is losing data when focus changes

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, riverpod

I have  textformfields like this : If i don't define a keyboardType for the second textformfield, there is no problem when i go through from first one to second field, i don't lose the first field's input. But if i define keyboardtype in my code, it loses the first field's data when i click on the second field.

Note : I am using riverpod as State Management.

```
class NewTx extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController titleController = TextEditingController(text: '');
  final TextEditingController priceController = TextEditingController(text: '');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, children: [
      TextFormField(
          controller: titleController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Title')
          ),
      TextFormField(
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          controller: priceController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Title')),
      Container(
          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomEnd,
          child: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.add),
              onPressed: () => context.read(transactionProvider).addTx(
                  Transaction(titleController.text, priceController.text))))
    ]);
  }
}
```

Edit : riverpod_hooks and useTextEditingController is working perfectly.(Another solution than stateful widget.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think issue is not in loosing focus, but rather in the fact that widget is rebuilt, it's class recreated and as consequence - controllers keeping text recreated.

I suggest changing NewTx to stateful widget and moving controllers to its state.

Comment: it is working but i feel like i shouldn't use stateful widget if i am using riverpod(which is a state management focusing on immutability,) Is my approach wrong ?(I am new on flutter and riverpod)

Comment: Thing is that TextControllers (as well as other controllers) are not reactive approach for thus you can not use simple state management to handle this well.

Comment: @sweCB It is not wrong to use Stateful widgets with Riverpod. If a state doesn't need to be global, don't make it global.

Comment: Moving all my variable declarations out from the widget build method, and placing them outside the method solved my problem.

Comment: That was my problem @DC007744 Thanks so much.
I had to remove all my `TextEditingController` variable decalarations out of the build method.

Answer (score 0):

```
final TextEditingController titleController = TextEditingController(text:''); 
final TextEditingController priceController = TextEditingController(text: '');
```

can u try like this?

```
final TextEditingController titleController = TextEditingController();
final TextEditingController priceController = TextEditingController();
```